# SignalR with Client Certificate Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, client-certificates

I have service hosted on IIS that uses SignalR to establish a persistent connection with a client.

I am attempting to implement client certificate authentication so that the server can verify that the client is a valid client based on the certificate they send. I am using Signalr's PersistentConnection.

Client: 
I create a Connection object, and i create a X.509 certificate which i add to the connection through:

```
var connection = new Connection("localhost:8060/TheService/connect");
connection.AddClientCertificate(certificate); 
connection.Start().Wait();
```

When the client attempts to connect, I want to verify that the certificate that it provides is a valid certificate. So on the server side I override the AuthorizeRequest() method in SignalR's PersistentConnection:

```
    public class MyConnection : PersistentConnection
    {
        protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
        {
            return Connection.Broadcast("Server Received: " + data);
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeRequest(IRequest request)
        {
            INameValueCollection headers = request.Headers;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in headers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            return true; 
        }
}
```

My question is: how do I retrieve the client certificate in the AuthorizeRequest method? I need SignalR to somehow gain access to the certificate so that I can verify it AuthorizeRequest and then either return false (bad cert), or return true (valid cert).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the certificate from the request you get as parameter.
`HttpClientCertificate cert = request.GetHttpContext().Request.ClientCertificate;`