# SignalR how to get client certificate when he connect to hub

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

How can i get client certificate when he connect to the signalr Hub? My code look like this i read certificate from file and then trying to connect to the hub. I want to create certifate object on hub and read some information from it.

Hub code:

```
public class ServerHub:Hub
{


    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        //get certificate ? `X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Certificate);`
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

Client code

```
string Certificate = @"C:\Users\StażCRM\Downloads\sample.cer";
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Certificate);
            string resultsTrue = cert.ToString(true);

            // Display the value to the console.
            Console.WriteLine(resultsTrue);

            // Get the value.
            string resultsFalse = cert.ToString(false);

            // Display the value to the console.
            Console.WriteLine(resultsFalse);


            this.id = id;

            HubConnection con = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:44375/ClinicServer",opt=>opt.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)).Build();
            con.StartAsync().Wait();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SignalR with Client Certificate Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003557/signalr-with-client-certificate-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer, you can get the certificate directly from the HttpContext.

[SignalR with Client Certificate Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003557/signalr-with-client-certificate-authentication?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, the code is for .NET framework.

When using asp.net core I think you can get the certificate like this

```
this.Context.GetHttpContext().Connection.ClientCertificate
```

Comment: Getting null all the time